How do I update an azure monitor LogSearchRuleResource using the python sdk?
I'd like to use the python sdk to retrieve and then update alerts in azure monitor. However, there seems to be an issue with the sdk where it will not understand that I'm updating an existing alert - as apposed to creating a new one. Here is my example:
from azure.core.credentials import AccessToken, TokenCredential
from azure.mgmt.monitor import MonitorManagementClient

credentials = AccessTokenCredential(AZURE_ACCESS_TOKEN)
monitor_client = MonitorManagementClient(credentials, AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)

alert_rule_name = "This is my alert_rule"
resource_group_name = "myresourcegroup"
alert_rule = monitor_client.scheduled_query_rules.get(
    resource_group_name,
    alert_rule_name)

monitor_client.scheduled_query_rules.create_or_update(
    resource_group_name,
    alert_rule_name,
    alert_rule)

This code is very simple - it authenticates (successfully in my case), retrieves an alert_rule (also successfully) of type from azure.mgmt.monitor.models.LogSearchRuleResource
, and then sends it right back.
The result:
HttpResponseError: (BadRequest) The query of a metric measurement alert rule must include an AggregatedValue column of a numeric type

This suggests to me that the sdk doesn't recognize this as an update, but instead a new alert. But it could also be some other issue with the SDK.
I would expect this resource - when returned to the API - to be a valid transaction with the server. Server gives me a resource that I requested. I give it back to the server - server should accept it. No?

Can you share the request body which you are using to create the scheduled_query_rules?

You need to have AggregatedValue in the query while creating Alert rule.
I have created an alert rule by using scheduled query rule Rest API for testing purpose and have used given request body.
{
  "location": "eastus2",
  "properties": {
    "description": "Performance rule",
    "severity": 4,
    "enabled": true,
    "evaluationFrequency": "PT5M",
    "scopes": [
      "/subscriptions/0e*****e7c/resourceGroups/******/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/afreenVM"
    ],
    "windowSize": "PT10M",
    "criteria": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "query": "Perf | where CounterValue >= 80 | summarize AggregatedValue = avg(['CounterValue']) by bin(TimeGenerated, 5m), Computer",
          "timeAggregation": "Average",
          "metricMeasureColumn": "AggregatedValue",
          "resourceIdColumn": "Computer",
          "dimensions": [
            {
              "name": "ComputerIp",
              "operator": "Exclude",
              "values": [
                "*****"
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "OSType",
              "operator": "Include",
              "values": [
                "*"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "operator": "GreaterThan",
          "threshold": 70,
          "failingPeriods": {
            "numberOfEvaluationPeriods": 1,
            "minFailingPeriodsToAlert": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "muteActionsDuration": "PT30M",
    "actions": {
    },
    "autoMitigate": false,
    "checkWorkspaceAlertsStorageConfigured": false,
    "skipQueryValidation": true
  }
}

Once the alert rule is created, I am using the below given code to update the description and got expected response.
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.monitor import MonitorManagementClient

sub_id = "0e******e7c"
monitor_client = MonitorManagementClient(credential=DefaultAzureCredential(), subscription_id=sub_id)

alert_rule_name = "afreenAlertRule"
resource_group_name = "******"

alert_rule = monitor_client.scheduled_query_rules.get(
    resource_group_name,
    alert_rule_name)

print("Current Alert Rule:\n", alert_rule)

alert_rule.description = "Updated Performance rule description"

updated_alert_rule = monitor_client.scheduled_query_rules.create_or_update(
    resource_group_name,
    alert_rule_name,
    alert_rule)

print("Updated Alert Rule:\n", updated_alert_rule)


